# Storing data from a equation into an array

Tags: .net, vb.net, cad

I'm trying to automate a 3D CAD program with Solid edge with Visual Basic 2003.

In there I want to make curve lines with an 4th degree equation.

I got the following form the Solid Edge SDK

> ```
> objBSplinecurves.AddByPoints(Order:=x, ArraySize:=x, Array:=x)
> ```

My question: is it possible to loop the equation, for example, from x*0.2 to x*1.5 (when 'x' is an constant like 9)

And then store these points into an array? I get stuck at storing them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any particular reason to why you are using VS 2003 (and not any of the newer versions)?

Comment: The company i'm an intern at only has this version. The company is an engeneering office and does't use visual basic for other things. I was lucky that IT had this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `X` is to be variable. So you should have said `9*x`, where `x=0.2:0.1:1.5` (in Matlab syntax). Anyway, this may help you get started:

```
Dim listOfMultipliers As New List(Of Double)
For i = 0.2 To 1.5 Step 0.1
  listOfMultipliers.Add(i)
Next
Dim multipliersArray() As Double = listOfMultipliers.ToArray()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! This will help me i think. But can only test it untill monday.